# php array_search not returning values

Tags: php

I am putting the contents of an text file into an array via the file() command. When I try and search the array for a specific value it does not seem to return any value but when I look at the contents of the array the value I am searching for is there.

Code used for putting text into array:

```
    $usernameFileHandle = fopen("passStuff/usernames.txt", "r+");
    $usernameFileContent = file("passStuff/usernames.txt");
    fclose($usernameFileHandle);
```

Code for searching the array

```
$inFileUsernameKey = array_search($username, $usernameFileContent);
```

Usernames.txt contains

```
Noah
Bob
Admin
```

And so does the $usernameFileContent Array. Why is array_search not working and is there a better way to do this. Please excuse my PHP noob-ness, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because [`file()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php):

> Returns the file in an array. Each element of the array corresponds to a line in the file, with the newline still attached

To prove this try the following:

```
var_dump(array_search('Bob
', $usernameFileContent));
```

You could use [`array_map()`](http://php.net/array_map) and [`trim()`](http://php.net/trim) to *correct* the behavior of `file()`. Or, alternatively, use [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/file_get_contents) and [`explode()`](http://php.net/explode).

Answer (score 1):

To quote [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php):

> Each element of the array corresponds to a line in the file, with the newline still attached.

That means that when you're doing the search, you're searching for `"Noah"` in an array that contains `"Noah\n"` - which doesn't match.

To fix this, you should run [`trim()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) on each element of your array before you do the search.

You can do that using [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) like this:

```
$usernameFileContent = array_map($usernameFileContent, 'trim');
```

Note, too, that the [`file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) function operates directly on the provided filename, and does not need a file handle. That means you to **do not** need to use [`fopen()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) or [`fclose()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fclose.php) - You can remove those two lines entirely.

So your final code could look like this:

```
$usernameFileContent = array_map(file('passStuff/usernames.txt'), 'trim');
$inFileUsernameKey = array_search($username, $usernameFileContent);
```

Comment: If you don't specify strict mode, shouldn't it return the key for "Noah\n" even if the needle is "Noah"?